# WorldToScreenPoint but still different positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have started using WorldToScreenPoint but the thing is the object is not the same on different screen sizes :(

heres my codes

```
    public virtual void Move()
    {
        Vector2 buttonFirst = thisCam.WorldToScreenPoint(gameButtons[0].transform.position);
        buttonFirst.x = 316.5f;  //242
        buttonFirst.y = 111f;
        gameButtons[0].transform.position = buttonFirst;
}
```

heres the output
[image]

Comment: Sorry from your image I don't understand what is supposed to happen and what goes wrong. Note that a different resolution results in different Screen coordinates

Comment: I want it to be on the same position on different screen size :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the object is not the same on different screen sizes

Of course, different size so different position.

If you need the return position to be invariable, use [WorldToViewportPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html), it always returns a value between (0,0) to (1,1).

Comment: Is my syntax correct?? I mean in Vector 2 = buttonFirst=thisCam.WorldToScreenPoint(gameButton[0].transform.position); ???

Comment: So I just need to change it to viewport then?

Comment: Viewport means the camera area size is always 1.0x1.0, after you got it, you still need to translate it by mutiple with the canvas/screen size.

Comment: @NicoleErasga, in fact the code you posted is almost odd, you use `WorldToScreenPoint` to translate the position, but next you overwrite it with a fixed position. It make the `WorldToScreenPoint` call useless.

Answer (score 0):

as I Understood you need to use ScreenToWorldPoint!

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

check this

Comment: How is this answer different to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54376867/7111561)?